# Passing object to partial view using ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

I'm going to build a helper for my application which uses many wizards.
For my views, there is simple call:

```
@using (var wiz = MyHelper.EditWizard(Translate(Keys.User.ChangePasswordTitle)))
{
    // RenderPartial(...)       
}
```

whereas `MyHelper` is a own implementation of `HtmlHelper` which has the original helper-object encapsulated as a property.

As a wizard can consist of multiple steps, the content can be splitted into multiple partial views.
The variable `wiz` has some public methods I need to access in my partial.

Question is, how can I pass the `wiz`-object?

Inside the `EditWizard()` I'm trying to add the wizard to the `ViewData`.

```
myHelper.HtmlInternal.ViewData["currentWizard"] = theWizard;
```

However, in my partial, the `ViewData`-dictionary is always empty. Currently I try to get the data with

```
var wiz = (Wizard)ViewData["currentWizard"];
```

But `wiz` is always `null`.

Comment: How is ViewData able to be seen by EditWizard?

Comment: The original `HtmlHelper` is part of my custom helper. `myHelper.HtmlInternal` is the original `HtmlHelper` object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I' ve ended up using

```
myHelper.HtmlInternal.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["currentWizard"] = theWizard;
```

in my helper-method and vice-versa in my partial view

```
var wiz = (Wizard)ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["currentWizard"]
```

Is there anything why this should never ever be used or is it legit?

Answer (score 5):

We use `HtmlHelper.Partial` which has, as its second argument, an object model:

```
@Html.Partial("YourWizardOrWhatever", wiz)
```

Wiz, in this case, is provided as the model for the partial view.  You can also forward your entire model:

```
@Html.Partial("YourWizardOrWhatever", Model)
```

Or you can use the anonymous type to craft up just a few arguments:

```
@Html.Partial("YourWizardOrWhatever", new { step = Model.Step, answer = Model.LastAnswerOrSomething })
```

Comment: `@Html.Partial("ChangePassword/_Password", Model, new ViewDataDictionary { {"wiz", wiz} })` seems to work. But, I still don't get the point why adding it inside the helper is not working